# C++ Inherit base constructor, but still call default derived constructor

Tags: c++, c++14

I've been struggling with this problem :

At the moment I have this code :

```
class B {
  public:
    B(int, int, int, int);
    [many other ctors]
};

class D : public B {
  public:
    using B::B;
    [other methode]
};
```

Now I want D to manage some pointer, that I need to initialize independently of the arguments passed to the constructors.

I have tried this :

```
class B {
  public:
    B(int, int, int, int) {
      [other stuff]
      init();
    }
    [many other ctors]
    virtual void init() {}
};

class D : public B {
  public:
    using B::B;
    void init() {
      mPointer = new Stuff(42);
    }

  private:
    mPointer = nullptr;
};
```

but apparently if you call a virtual method From B::B(int,int,int,int), it calls B::init, and not D::init.

Is there a nice way to make this work, or do I need to re-write all of B's ctors in D ?

Thanks !

Comment: [Interesting read](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/OOP50-CPP.+Do+not+invoke+virtual+functions+from+constructors+or+destructors)

Comment: It's explicitly the case that during a base-class constructor, the vtable and virtual functions are used for that base-class, not the eventual derived class. You may need to move to a factory pattern, to let you construct the object full and then call `init()` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other's have said, it is not trivially possible to call a derived virtual function inside a constructor, but it is not the only way to fix your problem, though.

In your specific case, which I understand as you wanting to initialize members of your inherited class but still reusing base class constructor, you can use in-class member initialization. This works:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Base {
  public:
    Base(int, int, int) { std::cout << "Calling base constructor" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    using Base::Base;
    std::string member{"This is a member string"};
};

int main() {
  Derived d(1, 2, 3);
  std::cout << d.member << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see [here](https://godbolt.org/g/eQR5JT), compiling above code with GCC (and with no optimizations) does generate a `Derived` constructor, and it calls `Base` constructor *and* initializes the `std::string` member.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call virtual functions from constructor. This has to do with the order of construction of your objects:

```
struct E {
    E() { std::cout << "E" << std::endl; }
    int g = 7;
};

struct F : E {
    B() { std::cout << "F" << g << std::endl; }
};

F f;
```

When constructing `f`, the program will output `EF7`. The base class is constructed first, so in the derived class you can call methods and use members from the parent.

In fact, with the simple example above, you can use the variable `g` in `F` constructor for the reason that the parent constructor is called before. Otherwise it would be ill formed, because `E`'s constructor is the one setting `g` to `7`

What does this have to do with your problem?

Well, in the base constructor, your are calling a virtual function. You expect the virtual function called to be dispatched in the derived class. The thing is, the is no derived class yet.

You see, the class `B` is constructed first. There is no `D` existing yet! Since no `D` exist yet, the virtual dispatch cannot be done to call `D` function! So instead, the compiler will fallback to functions that can be chosen at that moment. In your case, that function is `B` init function.

Comment: Sort of. Virtual dispatch technically happens, but you'd need three levels of inheritance to see it, and then you'd need to try from the intermediate level ctor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Virtual methods are called non-virtually from constructors, since derived class is not yet constructed when base class constructor is called.

This is a known way to end up calling pure virtual function - just call some intermediate function which calls pure virtual one from the constructor (you can't call pure virtual function from the constructor directly, compiler won't allow you).

To solve your problem, instead of inheriting constructors, declare your own and call base class constructor, followed by your specific initialization.